# Numpy array memory management

Tags: arrays, memory, numpy

I have a question about Numpy array memory management. Suppose I create a numpy array from a buffer using the following:

```
>>> s = "abcd"
>>> arr = numpy.frombuffer(buffer(s), dtype = numpy.uint8)
>>> arr.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : False
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> del s # What happens to arr?
```

In the situation above, does 'arr' hold a reference to 's'? If I delete 's', will this free the memory allocated for 's' and thus make 'arr' potentially referencing unallocated memory?

Some other questions I have:

- If this is valid, how does Python know when to free the memory allocated by 's'? The gc.get_referrents(arr) function doesn't seem to show that 'arr' holds a reference to 's'.
- If this is invalid, how can I register a reference to 's' into 'arr' so that Python GC will automatically reap 's' when all references to it are gone?

Answer (score 7):

The following should clarify things a little:

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> arr = np.frombuffer(buffer(s), dtype='uint8')
>>> arr.base
<read-only buffer for 0x03D1BA60, size -1, offset 0 at 0x03D1BA00>
>>> del s
>>> arr.base
<read-only buffer for 0x03D1BA60, size -1, offset 0 at 0x03D1BA00>
```

In the first case `del s` has no effect, because what the array is pointing to is a `buffer` created from it, which is not referenced anywhere else.

```
>>> t = buffer('abcd')
>>> arr = np.frombuffer(t, dtype='uint8')
>>> arr.base
<read-only buffer for 0x03D1BA60, size -1, offset 0 at 0x03C8D920>
>>> arr.base is t
True
>>> del t
>>> arr.base
<read-only buffer for 0x03D1BA60, size -1, offset 0 at 0x03C8D920>
```

In the second case, when you `del t`, you get rid of the variable `t` pointing to the `buffer` object, but because the array still has a reference to that same `buffer`, it is not deleted. While I am not sure how to check it, if you now `del arr`, the `buffer` object should lose its last reference and be automatically garbage-collected.

Comment: you can use sys.getrefcount in CPython to watch refcount increase for `s` in both cases. Not that it matters, it just works of course.

Answer (score 1):

In order to complement @seberg 's comment:

```
    import ctypes
    import sys

    import numpy as np

    b = bytearray([1, 2, 3])
    b_addr = id(b)
    print(sys.getrefcount(b) - 1, ctypes.c_long.from_address(b_addr).value)  # => 1 1
    a1 = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.int8)
    assert b[0] == a1[0]
    b[0] = b[0] + 1
    assert b[0] == a1[0]
    print(sys.getrefcount(b) - 1, ctypes.c_long.from_address(b_addr).value)  # => 2 2
    a2 = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.int8)
    print(sys.getrefcount(b) - 1, ctypes.c_long.from_address(b_addr).value)  # => 3 3
    del a2
    print(sys.getrefcount(b) - 1, ctypes.c_long.from_address(b_addr).value)  # => 2 2
    del b
    print(ctypes.c_long.from_address(b_addr).value)  # => 1
    del a1
    print(ctypes.c_long.from_address(b_addr).value)  # => 0
```

`sys.getrefcount(b)` returns a higher value *"because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount()"*