# In python how can I make data ready for garbage collection to free memory?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, garbage-collection

I have function that uses numpy to return an array with 4 fields. I use that function in a loop extract data from multiple sources. However my processing only is on 1 out of 4 fields. How do I reasonably make sure that the 3/4 fields I do not need will not be in memory before the next loop iteration? Here is my current approach:

```
data = []
for source in SOURCES:
    data_buff = read_source(source)    # data_buff has 4 fields ('a','b','c','d')
    data_buff = data_buff['a']         # only select required field
    data.append(data_buff)
```

Comment: The way I would approach this is to not use data_buff. You could just do `data.append(read_source(source)['a'])`, which wouldn't create temp variables.

Comment: But isn't `data.append(read_source(source)['a'])` implicitly loading *all* the fields into memory and passing one?

Comment: yes, but python knows that the data can never be accessed again, so it will clear it as soon as it can.

Comment: @OscarSmith: If `read_source(source)['a']` is an array, I'm pretty sure that's going to keep the whole original array. You'd need something like `data.append(read_source(source)['a'].copy())` to copy the part you want into a new array so the original can be freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a structured array; at least that's consistent with how you are accessing fields.

In my current ipython session I have a structured array with 3 fields, and 64 elements.

```
In [1383]: data1.shape
Out[1383]: (64,)
In [1384]: data1.dtype
Out[1384]: dtype([('f0', 'u1'), ('f1', 'u1'), ('f2', 'u1')])
In [1385]: data1.__array_interface__
Out[1385]: 
{'data': (163303000, False),
 'descr': [('f0', '|u1'), ('f1', '|u1'), ('f2', '|u1')],
 'shape': (64,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '|V3',
 'version': 3}
```

If I index one field, I get a `view` - same `data` buffer pointer:

```
In [1386]: data1['f0'].__array_interface__
Out[1386]: 
{'data': (163303000, False),
 'descr': [('', '|u1')],
 'shape': (64,),
 'strides': (3,),
 'typestr': '|u1',
 'version': 3}
```

But if I use `copy`, then I get a new data buffer.

```
In [1387]: data1['f0'].copy().__array_interface__
Out[1387]: 
{'data': (166164152, False),
 'descr': [('', '|u1')],
 'shape': (64,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '|u1',
 'version': 3}
```

So if I did `data1=data1['f0'].copy()`, and there aren't any other `views` of the original `data1`, that data buffer space will be recycled.

Most of the space used by an array is in the data buffer.  It's numpy itself that manages that, not the Python GC.  Obviously in one way or other they interact.  So I think the best thing is to just make sure you collect copies, not views.

Comment: eventually GC will do it either you accept it or not plus u can't free the memory cause again it's depends upon numpy or  one -other way of numpy and GC interaction

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure but i guess memory in python can't be freed, mean the memory occupied by some array or any object cannot be added to free memory pool programmatically even if you delete the reference variable. it will be deleted by the `GC` when the time comes.Try [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865075/numpy-array-memory-management) for example